# How can i change visibility of a grid declared in another class after successful login

Tags: wpf, grid, visibility

I have a class X and it has some buttons which are hidden under a grid . One of the button which is visible on double click  opens the login pop up (declared  in  Y class) . Now after the successful login I would like to make grid hidden (because buttons are behind that grid).
how can i make grid declared in X class Hidden after successful login in Y class.

```
class X code:

<Grid  Background="Black" x:Name="smallAGrid"  x:FieldModifier="public"   
 Opacity="0.8" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible" />
  <Grid Background="Black" x:Name="bigBGrid" x:FieldModifier="public"  
  Opacity="0.8"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="Visible"/>
     <Grid Name="ModeGrid" >
   <Button Content="Gateway" Height="42" x:Name="maintenanceMode"  
        Width="148" Click="maintenanceMode_Click"/>
        <Popup  Placement="Center" x:Name="passwordProtectionPopUp" 
             AllowsTransparency="True">
            <Grid>
                <local:Y Width="350" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0"   />                                                         
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>

class Y code:

private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  try
   {
       if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlCon.Open();
           //rest of the login code here
   }
          // after Successful login i would like to do
           X x = new X();
          x.smallAGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          }
     catch
    {
    }
```

Note:But Iam unable to change the visibility .After putting breakpoint , I checked it goes to my X class and this visibility function but it doesn't change it ???

Comment: Why don't you provide a callback function or and event in class Y, than before opening up a popup register for `Login_Success` callback/event inside clss X, and when that event/callback is called disable your buttonsunder grid

Comment: i don't want to disable my buttons under the grid. i just want  my grid to just cover my controls and once someone has logged in succesfully than the grid is hidden and they could see the buttons. How can I hide my grid in class X  from class Y.

Comment: what will happen in my Y class . i dont have a constructor to take these two parameters? Right now with the button click it opens the login window and on success displays a sucess message. Iam so confused?? –

Comment: Can't you modify it? Or at least return true if login successful, false otherwise

Comment: That look so complicated to me .I found much simpler way .Thanks for your help though @DipenShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found answer Its pretty simple Just declare control you want to access as static in the original class and assign them to the original control names  and in other class where you want to access do this:

```
y class code
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   try
     {
        if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
          //rest of the login code here
             Grid vr= X.small;
            vr.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          }

      catch
    {
    }
      X Class code
      public static Grid small;
    public X()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     small= smallAGrid // (name of grid control)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have class X representing a parent window and class Y representing login window, you could use something similar to:

```
Class X
{
    Control grid;    //grid which you want to show/hide
    Button btnLogin; //button which opens up login window

    public void BtnLogin_DoubleClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var loginWindow = new Y(LoginSuccessCallback, LoginFailureCallback);
        loginWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void LoginSuccessCallback()
    {
        grid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void LoginFailureCallback()
    {
        grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```